# How to shrinkwrap symlink node module created with 'npm link'?

Tags: node.js, npm, symlink, shrinkwrap, npm-shrinkwrap

I work on two repositories at once. One depends on the other (listed in `package.json` dependencies).

So I am using `npm link ..\theOne` in `other` to work on both modules at once. As a result I can test the modification on one module on the other. Problem is when doing `npm shrinkwrap` on this `other` module: it will generate errors like:

`npm ERR! extraneous C:\other\node_modules\theOne\node_modules\{xxxx}`

`{xxxx}` is a dev dependencies that appears as extraneous for npm.

Anyone has succeded to shrinkwrap a module with symlink to another modules?

NB:

- npm 3.10.3
- node 6.3.0

Comment: for me shrinkwrap itself did work but then any subsequent attempt to `npm link theOne && npm install` fails by saying "Not found : theOne"

Comment: did you try `npm link ../theOne` ? I mean, using a relative path?

Comment: Actually my issue was due to typescript. After fixing that it works fine and yes npm shrinkwrap worked fine too. Maybe share your code in plunker?

Answer (score 0):

I post a solution here. It doesn't explain how to shrinkwrap symlinks but I found a better workaround to develop multiple modules at once with dependencies between those modules.

The solution is to use an alternative to `npm link` to handle the modules relations during development: Instead of having a folder *A* linked to another folder *B* (aka symlink), the solution is to have the modified files from *B* copied in folder *A*. This solution is very powerful because it avoid getting node module shrinkwrapping error due to unwanted modules from *B*. How to do it:

#### On Mac

You can use [wml](https://github.com/wix/wml): Wml listens to changes in some folder (using Watchman) and copies changed files into another folder. I never use it but my teammate using Mac use it every day.

#### On Window

I use [DSynchronize](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) (after clicking this link, scroll down to see the executable). DSynchronize is a stand-alone utility that let you periodically synchronize two or more folders. You can exclude from copying some folders (like `node_modules`) or include others (like `lib`). The configuration file `DSynchronize.ini` can be edited with a text editor. For example:

```
Source0000=-C:\DEV\workspace\js-common
Destination0000=-C:\DEV\workspace\connexme\node_modules\js-common
Filter0000=
VolumeSerialOri0000=407325536
VolumeSerialDest0000=407325536
ExcludeFilter0000=0
NoSubDirectory0000=0
NoFilterDirectory0000=1
DateBeforeToExcludeFiles0000=00:00:00
FilterFolder0000=\.git|\.vscode|\node_modules
```

This configuration will copy file from `C:\DEV\workspace\js-common` to `C:\DEV\workspace\connexme\node_modules\js-common`. This way, when I `npm shrinkwrap` my project connexme, I'll doesn't get extraneous bad folder from `js-common` folder.

Just a three last things about editing `DSynchronize.ini` for [DSynchronize](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) configuration:

- Using it or closing it will save the configuration in `DSynchronize.ini` so be careful when editing `DSynchronize.ini`and the closing it. It will override `DSynchronize.ini`.
- Make sure each variables is unique. Example: `Source0000`, `Source0001`...
- Make sure to have all the variables present for each Source/Destinations (see example above).